# How to stop a buggy pulumi.dynamic.ResourceProvider?

Tags: pulumi

I am attempting to shut down an ec2 instance with a dynamic resource dependency. The dynamic resource implementation is buggy, so `destroy()` always returns an error code and aborts the shutdown.

I have fixed the `destroy()` implementation, but I am unable to deploy the new provider instance because the old implementation keeps on getting used. What options are available in this case? Do I need to manually shut down the instance myself in order to deploy a new instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`destroy` runs the code which was defined at the time of the resource creation.

One option is to remove the buggy dynamic resource from your stack file manually.

Use [`pulumi state delete`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/pulumi_state_delete/#pulumi-state-delete) or a sequence of (1) `pulumi stack export` (2) edit the state file to exclude the resource (3) `pulumi stack import`.

After this is done, the next `pulumi up` should create a new instance of the resource and the next `destroy` will run the updated code.